# updating setListAdapter from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am using this [Tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/) and its [sourcecodes](https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-listview-custom-view)  to make listview in android. I had implemented using this tutorial but during updating the `setListAdapter` i cannot update the `listview` dynamically. 
I have gone through many stackoverflow questions and they are giving  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` as the solution. But i am unable to implement it in AsyncTask.

**ItemListFragment.java**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), setArray(getActivity())));
    return v;
}

public ArrayList<Item> setArray(Context context)
{
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
    RealmResults<Books> bs = realm.where(Books.class).findAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap url = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bs.get(i).getCover());
        String title = bs.get(i).getName();
        String description = bs.get(i).getAuthor();
        Item item = new Item(url, title, description);
        items.add(item);
    }
    realm.close();
    return items;
}
}
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ItemView itemView = (ItemView) convertView;
    if (null == itemView)
    {
        itemView = ItemView.inflate(parent);
    }
    itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
    return itemView;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (id == R.id.update) {
        Update update = new Update(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.this);
        update.execute();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);
}
}
```

**Update.java**

```
public class Update extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

private Context context;
public Activity activity;

 public Update(Context context, Activity activity)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
}

    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ServerAddress = context.getString(R.string.ServerAddress);
    StringExtras = context.getString(R.string.CheckBook);
    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(ServerAddress + StringExtras);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("Response Code",responseCode+"");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
        String InputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        while ((InputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(InputLine);
        }
        br.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        Log.i("Response Data", response.toString());

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.toString());
        //booksList = Arrays.asList(books);
        //JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("cover");

        realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
        for (int i=0; i< array.length(); i++ ) {
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Books books = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), Books.class);
            Publish(books, realm);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (realm != null){
            realm.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //i want to call the setarray that contains my database data which has been updated on `doinbackground` and update the listview accordingly.
//The below codes are just the codes that i have tried but what should i do to update the listview.
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ItemListFragment activity1 = new ItemListFragment();
            ArrayList<Item> arrayList = activity1.setArray(context);
            List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
            int i = 0;
            for (Item item : arrayList)
            {
                list.add(arrayList.get(i));
                i++;
            }
            activity1.arrayAdapter.addAll(list);
            activity1.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

   }
```

I am trying to update the listview from postexcution. So, how can i update the view through it.

**Error From AsyncTask**

just incase you need but it's not the problem

```
8-30 16:31:47.976    1167-1167/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at np.com.thefourthgeneration.Update$1.run(Update.java:124)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4673)
        at np.com.thefourthgeneration.Update.onPostExecute(Update.java:108)
        at np.com.thefourthgeneration.Update.onPostExecute(Update.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You dont need to write runOnUiThread in onPostExecute method, because  onPostExecute runs on main thread. Just call notifyDataSetChanged in onPostExecute.

Comment: is notifDataSetChanged() not working for you ?

Comment: For what you are creating the new instance of ItemListFragment? For what several times creating ArrayList? Where placed class Update - in Activity? What`s the problem - you can`t clear adapter, or can`t update it or reised some error? Provide more code and be specific in the question.

Comment: I will advise you read a bit more about android background services. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @umerk44 Yes notifyDataSetChanged() method is not working.

Comment: @kolombo  The problem is that i am trying to update my listview on postexecution and cannot update it, as the error points to addAll() method and says `null pointer exception`. Also i am not getting what is causing the problem as the arrayList is `not null`

Comment: @PaladiN at the first blush you get NullPointerException because you create new instance of ItemListFragment but arrayAdapter in this instance are null. Provide full code of your Activity, Update class, ItemAdapter, ItemListFragment etc...

Comment: @kolombo updated the codes. Now can you help me? If anything you are not clear can say me. I can update again. Thankyou

Comment: @kolombo I have used those codes from https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-listview-custom-view

Answer (score 0):

**layout/activity_list**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/list_fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        itemListFragment = (ItemListFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(ItemListFragment.class.getSimpleName());
        if (itemListFragment == null) {
            itemListFragment = new ItemListFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, itemListFragment, ItemListFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemListFragment**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ListView listView;
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), itemArrayList);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.update:
                new Update(getActivity()).execute();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    public class Update extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private Context context;

        public Update(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServerAddress = context.getString(R.string.ServerAddress);
            StringExtras = context.getString(R.string.CheckBook);
            Realm realm = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(ServerAddress + StringExtras);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
                httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                httpURLConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();

                int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                Log.i("Response Code", responseCode + "");

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                String InputLine;
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                while ((InputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(InputLine);
                }
                br.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                Log.i("Response Data", response.toString());

                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                //booksList = Arrays.asList(books);
                //JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("cover");

                realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    Books books = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), Books.class);
                    Publish(books, realm);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (realm != null) {
                    realm.close();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            itemArrayList.clear();
            itemArrayList.addAll(getArray(context));
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public ArrayList<Item> getArray(Context context) {
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
            Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
            RealmResults<Books> bs = realm.where(Books.class).findAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < bs.size(); i++) {
                Bitmap url = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bs.get(i).getCover());
                String title = bs.get(i).getName();
                String description = bs.get(i).getAuthor();
                Item item = new Item(url, title, description);
                items.add(item);
            }
            realm.close();
            return items;
        }

    }

    public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
    {

        public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
            super(context, 0, items);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ItemView itemView = (ItemView) convertView;
            if (null == itemView) {
                itemView = ItemView.inflate(parent);
            }
            itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Its not the 100% work code, because i dont fully understand all structures (like Realm) and I dont test it, but its the main idea.

Comment: how did you accessed `itemArrayList` of `class ItemListFragment` that is `private ` can you please explain it?

Comment: @PaladiN itemArrayList its a private member of ItemListFragment and ItemListFragment has full access of itemArrayList. I moved all the code into the fragment - Update and Adapter classes placed inside ItemListFragment and also has access to private members of outer class (of ItemListFragment). So you do not need to reference to the Activity or something else - all work is performed in the ItemListFragment. If you need to have access itemArrayList in other fragments - you can transmit it (itemArrayList) over the activity.

Comment: @PaladiN did you try this code? Did you try to understand it? Is it helpfull for you? I write this code to help you, if you realy need this. Not for you just look on this and say "Ohh whatever..."

Comment: I am a little bit busy doing other stuffs, so i haven't tried it. I will try and reply you tomorrow.